# Modify some collection elements independent of collection type

Tags: python, collections, iterator

I'm trying to write function which could modify elements (of string type) in collection of any type (list, dict, etc) or creates new collection of the same type with the same elements, but modified according to my rules.

I'm pretty new in python and I have a general question, but will describe the specific situation to be more clear.

I have fixed case-sensitive format of MAC addresses in MongoDB like `12:34:56:78:9a:bc`. As we know `12:34:56:78:9a:bc`, `12:34:56:78:9A:BC`, `12-34-56-78-9A-BC` and  `123456789abc` are the same values for us and for physical representation, but they are different in MongoDB. So my function will check if the string represents MAC address and convert it to required format. But I want it to accept list of strings, dict of strings as values, (maybe) tuples of strings, dict of lists of strings, etc, to change their values.

So what I have for now:

```py
def formMacAddress(addr):
    if type(addr) is str:
        addr = addr.lower()
        if not re.match('[0-9a-f]{2}([-:]?)[0-9a-f]{2}(\\1[0-9a-f]{2}){4}$', 
                addr):
            raise ValueError("'{addr}' is not MAC address".format(addr=addr))
        return re.sub('([0-9a-f]{2})[-:]?', '\g<1>:', addr, 5)
    if type(addr) is dict:
        res = {}
        for k, v in addr.items():
            res[k] = formMacAddress(v)
        return res
    if type(addr) is list:
        res = list(addr)
        for k, v in enumerate(addr):
            res[k] = formMacAddress(v)
        return res
    raise ValueError("'{addr}' is not MAC address".format(addr=addr))
```

So the problem is that I do not like checks for collection types with the same bodies. There are could be much more types in the future. I expected from python an ability to avoid this.

In C++ for example I could use set iterators. In lua only one collection type could be. But I can not find the proper way to do this with python. I can not set values using iterators, the `items()` method does not exists in lists and `enumerate()` is applicable only to lists to access their elements with indexes while looping. What I'm missing?

Comment: So you simply want to iterate over generic collection in python? Couldnt it be simply done in a for loop:`for ad in i addr:`

Comment: @running.t, where and how to put modified ``ad`` to the new version of ``addr`` collection then?

Answer (score 0):

you could iterate through dict or list or tuple : (you have to isolate the type str)

```
def formMacAddress(addr):
    seq_iter = addr if isinstance(addr, dict) else range(len(addr))
    print(seq_iter)
    for i in seq_iter:
        print(addr[i])

formMacAddress({"0":"12","1":"34"})
formMacAddress(["0","12"])
formMacAddress(("1","12"))
```

output:

```
{'0': '12', '1': '34'}
12
34
range(0, 2)
0
12
range(0, 2)
1
12
```

Comment: But there could be other collections except dict with access by non-numeric keys

Comment: give a sample please?

Comment: Any user-defined class with similar to dict API, but based on the list. For example special implementation of hash-table with list as base class and dicts as second-level elements. Say, the access granted by string, taking the code of first character as index of the first-level list. It has well defined API similar to dict, but with own extra logic. This won't appear in my case for sure, but my question is conceptional. Ho to avoid any type check and use only common API? Without assuming any different in types? Again like in C++: just set iterators for any case even the most specific case!

Comment: sorry its my best answer , the only thing i could see is to create your self module and import it and in your program, you do all tests..